# UICollectionView didSelectItemAt method doesn't work

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I need to give some logic when I'm taping on items in UICollectionView but my didSelectItemAt method doesn't work

Here is my code of ViewController

```
class NewGalleryViewController: UIViewController {
var presenter: ViewToPresenterPhotoProtocol?
var builder: GalleryRequestBuilder?

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

let reuseIdentifier = "customCVCell"


@objc func refresh() {
    presenter?.refresh()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    self.setupPresenterIfNeed()
    presenter?.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func setupPresenterIfNeed() {
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    if self.presenter == nil {
        let presenter = GalleryPresenter()
        presenter.view = self
        self.presenter = presenter
        self.builder = GalleryRequestBuilder()
    }
}
}

extension NewGalleryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.presenter?.photos.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.cellSetup(photo: (self.presenter?.photos[indexPath.item])!)
    
    if indexPath.row == (self.presenter?.photos.count)! - 1 {
        self.presenter?.fetchNewPhotos()
    }
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 180, height: 128)
}

private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("test Tap")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
                        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0
}
}

extension NewGalleryViewController: PresenterToViewPhotoProtocol{
func onFetchPhotoSuccess() {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    self.collectionView!.layoutSubviews()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func onFetchPhotoFailure(error: String) {
    print("View receives the response from Presenter with error: \(error)")
    self.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}


}
```

And Here is my code of CollectioViewCell

```
class PhotoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var builder = GalleryRequestBuilder()

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    // Initialization code
}

@objc func navigateToDetailView() {
    
}

func cellSetup(photo: Photo) {
    self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: builder.createImageUrl(name: photo.image.name))
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.opaqueSeparator.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1

    
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

}

I thought that problem could be in ImageView but after removing it didSelectItemAt method still not working.

And here is GitHub repository if you need additional information https://github.com/Feetelcore/SwiftWebantGallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are defining didSelectItemAtIndexPath function private. When you do like that it's not stands for delegate function of UICollectionView. You should remove the private from the function and define like below.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("siski")    }
```

Comment: I'm getting warning
Instance method 'collectionView(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)' of protocol 'UICollectionViewDelegate'
Make 'collectionView(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)' private to silence this warning

Comment: Because you are writing wrongly it says nearly matches not exactly matches probably you are doing a typo error. So just write didSelect and let the xCode auto complete it. I download your repo and do it same it's working. @Ivanius

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're missing `delegate`. Add this line in `viewDidload` and try again:

```swift
collectionView.delegate = self
```

Comment: You are using `private` for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Please remove `private` and conform the delegate by suggestion again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but apparently it's root cause is different. But I will still write the solution there because searching for *didSelectItemAt related problems etc* returns this page as first result on the search engine.

In my scenario, I had a custom xib for the cell and I have placed an invisible button covering all of the view placed there. Don't ask why lol. Just a beginner approach.

The button were somehow hijacking the tap. Removed this button and `didSelectItemAt` works as expected now. Implement a new method in cell class and call the method from `didSelectItemAt` instead of relying on `@IBAction` of button touch event.